# How to localize Metro MessageBox buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I need to localize [Metro MessageBox buttons](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/).

I have already tried following code but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-UY");

Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

var dialogResult = MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure to localize buttons?", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not documented at all.

But finally I got solution.

> 1. Take a look at the `MetroFramework.Demo` project. It has `Localization` folder.
> 2. Copy this folder to you Visual Studio project and include into project.
> 3. Create folder using two letters for instance let's use **`es`** (Spanish).
> 4. Copy and paste `MetroMessageBoxControl.xml` file from de folder to the new **`es`** folder and apply Build Action attribute for this file
>      like Embedded Resource.
> 5. In place you need just change culture of your app to Spanish.

It works!